# Javascript code automated minification

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification

I want to minify my existing javascript code and I want to achieve something like what we do for css preprocessors. We write in scss file and it gets converted into .css file on its own when the scss file is saved. Similary I want to achieve if I write in js file and save it ,the code gets minified and gets saved in minified file on its own.

Is there any way to achieve this kind of functionality ?

Comment: Have you searched this online? Did it yield any results?

Comment: You can js code minify..google it

Comment: Use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js

Comment: @Sanjay is this package provides functionality of automatic writing in js file and getting saved in minified file ?

Comment: Are you using Node?

Comment: @Sanjay No, not using node.

Comment: @NishantKumar Which code editor are you using?

Comment: @Sanjay Atom and visual studio

Comment: @NishantKumar Check the answer I wrote!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Atom, you need this package:

- Atom Minify: https://atom.io/packages/atom-minify

If you are using Sublime, you need this package:

- Minify on Save: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Minify%20on%20Save

Both packages can minify on save!